# UIWebView PDF hyperlink disable action sheet

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiwebview

I am working on a native ios app that downloads a pdf from my server in which the pdf is loaded in `UIWebView` 
here is the code:-

```
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/test.pdf"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

the image below shows the action sheet that display when I long press a hyperlink in the pdf, I want to disable or avoid the action sheet, or if there is another solution to load a pdf with hyperlinks and avoids the action sheet that will be helpful.

I am using Xcode 5.0 iOS 7

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182470/uiwebview-contextual-menu-while-displaying-pdf-content?rq=1